# 14.04 Can't do updates, can't update to 15

Tags: updates

I recently tried to install a few packages on ubuntu 14.04 and they failed.  At first I thought it was just one package, but it is a general failure of apt-get.  For example:

```
$ mono

The program 'mono' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
```

and when I try to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-62-generic (= 3.16.0-62.83~14.04.1) but 3.16.0-62.82~14.04.1 is to be installed
 mono-runtime : Depends: mono-runtime-sgen (= 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I thought perhaps 14.04 is in end of life so I looked into upgrading.  But the updater crashes with a requester:

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
```

I unclicked and removed all third party repositories.  Same error.
How can I uncorrupt?  What is even wrong?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: 14.04 doesn't reach its end-of-life until 2019. There's some other issue. Please [edit] in the result of the commands @muru provided.

Answer (score 0):

After removing and purging all 3rd party repository, run 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y'

Hope it will help, thanks